# SublimeText: Change line endings of all files in a project

Tags: sublimetext3, line-endings

Sublime Text 3 has a very useful feature to change Windows to Unix line endings on a file per file basis under `View` > `Line Endings`. Is it possible to do this for a whole project and/or directory at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Line​Endings plugin / package](https://github.com/titoBouzout/LineEndings) is small, but works like a charm Visit it's GitHub repository to get a few details, because on its Package Control page there is no description.

It not only works, but also gives you an additional functionality -- you can change not only line endings, but also indentation method of all open files in one step.

After installation:

```
1-Open all files, in which you want to convert / change line endings and/or indentation method.

2-Press Ctrl+Shift+P, to bring Command Pallete and start typing lin to locate Line Ending to all views: Windows (for example).

3-Select it, hit Enter, and... you're done!

4-Repeat step 2, but type spaces to locate Indentation: Convert to all views to Spaces or tabs to locate Indentation: Convert to all views to Tabs to change indentation method of all open files.
```